# Detect which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In briefly, I load a local HTML page into a `div` inside other web form in asp.net.

JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#includedContent").load("../HtmlHolder/index.html");
    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="includedContent" class="WebHolder" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #808080; margin: 0px auto; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
```

Now I want to get element's class name by click on them by below script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.WebHolder').on("click", "*", function (e) {

            alert("Class :" + $(this).attr("class"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Problem is, when I click on any element, this code alert this Class name and it's Parent!

How to resolve it?

Note: element is not specific object, maybe it's an input or button or textarea or ... .

Comment: Don't you get multiple `alerts` ?

Comment: Do you even need the `*`? Can just be `on("click", function (e) ...`, then `e.target` to access the clicked element

Comment: @RayonDabre, yes ,i've multiple alert. => for example first alert is textbox alert then it's parent then  it's parent then  it's parent ....

Comment: @PetrGazarov ,yes i need it. I put it to get all element ,such as input,button ,textarea and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `e.target`(*Use this as selector*) not `this`(*Because it is the parent*)

`alert("Class :" + $(e.target).attr("class"));`

**To avoid performing the action on parent:** You can compare `this` and `e.target` to validate if it is the parent.

`if( this !== e.target )`

**CODE SNIPPET FOR DEMO:**

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e){

    if( this !== e.target ) alert( 'Class is '+ $(e.target).attr('class') );

});
```

```css
div{
  background: #fe7a15; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
  I am the parent, Clicking me will not get you an alert but headers does, because they are my children.
  <br /><br />
  <h1 class="class-header-child-one">Header 1</h1>
  <h2 class="class-header-child-two">Header 2</h2>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Still you need to prevent the propagation!

Comment: This is a good solution ,BUT I've unnecessary alert,when I click on form's element.if I click on it,I'll see it's class that I don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in the event handler.

```
$('.WebHolder').on("click", "*", function (e) {

    alert("Class :" + $(this).attr("class"));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the event bubbling up the DOM tree.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '*', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
div > div {
  background: orange;
}
div > div > div {
  background: yellow;
}
div > div > div > div {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Main
    <div>1
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>13
            <div>131</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution is good too, but i've unnecessary alert yet... .
How to resolve it?

Comment: @HamidTalebi Can you create live demo on jsfiddle.net